# Python Zip function out of sync

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I'm using a for loop with a zip function to iterate through a large amount of data.

The data is distance and time and the data base is extremely large.
Normally the time column has an iteration every 10th of a second ie. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 etc.

Very occasionally however a random value gets thrown in ie. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4 etc.

This puts df1 out of sync with df2.

Is there a way to filter this out? I have put my code below:

```
for x, y in list(zip(df1.loc['time'], df2.loc['time'])):
    print df1.loc['dist'][df1.loc['time'] == x] - df2.loc['dist'][df1.loc['time'] == y]
```

The results I get look like this:

```
1    0.0
Name: dist, dtype: float64
2   -0.01
Name: dist, dtype: float64
3   -0.02
Name: dist, dtype: float64
4   -0.03
Name: dist, dtype: float64
5   -0.05
Name: dist, dtype: float64
6   -0.06
Name: dist, dtype: float64
7   -0.06
Name: dist, dtype: float64
7   NaN
8   NaN
Name: dist, dtype: float64
7   NaN
9   NaN
```

You can see around iteration 7 there was a piece of data that put extra values in so iter 8 was out of sync.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You could just filter the df first so `df[df['dist'].diff() > 0]` or `df[df['dist'].diff() > == 0.01]`

Comment: Hi Ed thanks for replying. I just get a KeyError: 'dist'     if I use that?

Comment: Sorry are you substituing `df1` and `df2` in place of `df` in my code snippet?

Comment: Yes and in the second one it's expecting another expression

Comment: you also don't need to call list on the zip object

Comment: Could you paste a small sample of your data frames? I'm guessing they have rows labelled 'time' and 'dist', not columns. My first try would be: `df_filtered = df.loc[:, df.loc['time'] == np.round(df.loc['time'],1) ]` or `df_filtered = df.loc[:, np.abs(df.loc['time'] - np.round(df.loc['time'],1)) > 0.00001 ]`. Also: what is the value in 'dist' for the corresponding random value at 'time'?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use usual join or merge?

Something like

```
df1.set_index('time')
df2.set_index('time')
jnd = df1.join(df2, how='inner', lsuffix='_1', rsuffix='_2')
jnd['delta_dist'] = jnd['dist_1'] - jnd['dist_2']
```